# How to compute total number percentage for slider width?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to modify slider: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c8ht3sjbXNmAjlrTuBOk?p=preview), to update progress bar percentage like total numbers value, so that it would jump between steps during sliding. How to compute round percentages as value in slider?

Function responsible for this:

```
function mousemove(event) {
  scope.percent = Math.max(0, Math.min((event.clientX - scope.l) / scope.w * 100, 100));
  if(scope.updateOnDrag)
  {
    scope.update();
  }
  scope.redraw();
}
```

Comment: so you want it to snap?

Comment: I would snap progress bar in relation to current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the `left`/`distance` value using Math.round()

```
scope.redraw = function() {
      var percentMultiplier = scope.percent / 100;
      var steppedPercent = (Math.round(percentMultiplier * scope.range) / scope.range) * 100;

      scope.btn.css({'display': ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$viewValue) ? 'none' : 'block'});
      scope.btn.css({'left': steppedPercent + '%'});
      scope.bar.css({'width': steppedPercent + '%'});
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working properly only when scope max is set on 10, if it is eg. 30 then progress bar value is shown three at every step. Example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9b96OOR19Q1RNFfm0fB?p=preview)

Comment: Updated my answer. I gave the wrong solution because I was only focused on the function you provided, but that's not actually the right place to do this. The percentage in that function was being calculated just fine.
By the way, when programming I recommend percentage multipliers (0-1) instead of percent (0-100). Percent is easier to understand for regular folk, but a multiplier is more useful for calculations. Forget about percentages until you really need it (the css part).